# Android API with custom View IDs

Tags: android, xml

For things like the built-in Android `ListView`, you can reference IDs in XML by doing `android:id="@android:id/text1"`

Let's say I have an external library called `MyDomain` in which I have some useful Layout APIs.

In my main app, I would like to do something like `android:id="@mydomain:id/someTextId"`.

How can I accomplish this?

I'm using Android Studio version 0.8.6 beta and (for the time being) have the Library as a Module if it makes any difference

Comment: This is not easily possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good explanation in this post [How to reference a string from another package in a library using XML in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262807/how-to-reference-a-string-from-another-package-in-a-library-using-xml-in-android) on the meaning of "package" there and why you can´t use it like so unless u´re using shared libraries

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you exactly wants to do...

You can share a component of your library with your app. The layout of the application will be something like this:

```
<com.my.domain.MyComponent
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
/>
```

You can also define custom properties of your component directly in the layout by adding an XML namespace, for instance:

```
xmlns:md="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.domain.MyComponent"
```

And then you can use a property like `md:my_property="42"`.

Also check this answer: [How can I set up custom namespaces in layout file in Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097961/how-can-i-set-up-custom-namespaces-in-layout-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want custom properties. I just want to specify my own IDs for resource files to use. For example when using a ListView in XML, you can use `android:id="@android:id/list"`. I still want to use `android:id`, but I want to be able to allow use of IDs from my own external package like `android:id="@mylib:id/headerView"`